# Поймать id form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите как получить id формы?
побывал вот так не выходит

```
console.log($("form").attr("id"));
```

Выдает undefined

Работает все на Yii2 скрипты js в конце тела

Comment: У меня выходит. [mcve] с демонстрацией проблемы в студию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
      console.log($("form").attr("id"));
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="test_form">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Подскажите а если код js идет в конце файла html? как быть в такой ситуации? Если пытаюсь получить id по классу например или наоборот все работает.

Comment: Попробуйте в конце файла, должно работать.

Comment: Странно но запустил именно ваш код в отдельном файле и он работает. Может Yii где то какие то ограничения дает.

Comment: Нашел ошибку. На странице оказалась еще одна форма logout, у которой адишник не задан! Нашел по такому коду $("form").attr("id", "pidor"); после выполнения искал в иходниках по контексту))))